# CSS background distorted upon hover

Tags: html, css

I came accross this problem while adding anchor elements to a  section for a menu. I want each element to display a transparent block of color behind it when the mouse is hovering over. At the same time, I want the page background to have stripes from CSS (background: linear-gradient; or background:repeating-linear-gradient;) (I run into this problem with either). When I have a link on top of these vertical stripes and I hover over it, the underlying stripes are shifted in one direction by about a pixel. Its a very small effect but none-the-less frustrating. I have removed all other elements from the html and css that are not involved in this issue and placed the resulting files in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bw9fk0y4/5/

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,transparent, transparent 2%, rgba(0,0,250,0.2) 2%, rgba(0,0,250,0.2) 4%, transparent 4%); 
  }

div nav{
      position: relative;
      left: 250px;
      }

div nav a{
        margin: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
      }

div nav a:hover{
          background-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.4);
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id = "container">
        <nav>
            <a href = "#">link 1</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

What I have found is that for some reason I don't run into this effect when the anchor is further to the right of this page. If it is centered or closer to the left side or even centered I do have this effect, even if I position it by setting a fixed width and the in CSS (margin: 0 auto;). If anyone knows of a way to aleviate this problem I would be very happy. This is only happening in chrome. I've tried using the browser specific gradients, no difference. I am afraid that this is just a result of CSS gradients not behaving well, because they seem to misbehave quite easily when played around with, but they are too convenient for me to give up on them easily.

Comment: I messed around with this for awhile, has me stumped !
maybe go with a slice repeat for your background until this is solved :(   It most definitely because of the rgba background.. but i cant find whats making it conflict...

Comment: Not seeing the problem in either FF30 or Chrome38

Comment: @JayD i switched to all hex colors and its still happening.